Is there a R function for calculating the sample size for a stepped wedge cluster RCT cohort study with binary outcomes?
I have been trying to calculate the sample size for a stepped wedge cluster RCT cohort study with binary outcomes. The problem is that the sample size I have been getting is really low and cannot be used for the study.
I have 28 clusters, and 3 steps. It is a one-tailed test design.
Where do I go from here because there are so many unknowns?
I have tried the sdwpwr function in R, tried to apply several formulas from different papers but nothing has worked yet.
